# react-query invalidateQueries not working with prefix / URLs

Tags: react-query

I'm using `react-query` 3.30 in an Ionic React app.

I have a paged query:

```
export function useCardAdmin(
  currentJsonUrl: string,
): UseQueryResult<JsonDataWidgetPagerRead, Error> {
  const query = currentJsonUrl;
  const queryKey = queryKeyUseWidgetAdmin(currentJsonUrl);
  return useQuery<JsonDataWidgetPagerRead, Error>(
    queryKey,
    async () => fetchAuth(query, true),
    {
      keepPreviousData: true,
      staleTime: DAY_MILLISECONDS,
      cacheTime: DAY_MILLISECONDS,
    },
  );
}

export const queryKeyUseWidgetAdmin = (currentJsonUrl: string): string => (`getWidgetAdmin${currentJsonUrl}`);
```

This is working fine.

A typical query key value is `getCardsAdminhttps://example.com/jsonapi/widgets?&fields[widget]=id,drupalId,part,gadget,refGroup&filter[uid.id][value]=adadfasf-f992-489c-9519-038f1728e0db&sort=-created&page[limit]=25`

However, when a user updates a widget (PATCH to server), then I need to invalidate the query.

So I tried this:

`queryClient.invalidateQueries('getWidgetAdmin')`

I expected all queries that begin with `getWidgetAdmin` to be invalidated [because the documentation says that the argument to invalidateQueries is treated as a prefix](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/query-invalidation). However, none of them are invalidated.

If I use the exact query key, like this:

`queryClient.invalidateQueries(queryKeyUseWidgetAdmin(currentJsonUrl))`

then the query is invalidated.  But I want to invalidate all the queries that begin with `getWidgetAdmin`, not just one of them.

I also tried setting `exact`:

`queryClient.invalidateQueries('getWidgetAdmin', { exact: false })`

This didn't work, either.

**How can I invalidate a group of queries in `react-query`?**

Additional info:

I was initializing `QueryClient()` with some custom config, but even when I initialize `queryClient` without any config (`const queryClient = new QueryClient();`), I still get the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fuzzy query key matching only works for Arrays. So if your key is:

```
['getWidgetAdmin', some, more, filters]
```

You can fuzzily invalidate with:

```
queryClient.invalidateQueries(['getWidgetAdmin'])
```

if it really needs to be a string startsWith, you can supply a predicate function (see the [QueryFilters documentation](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/filters)):

```
queryClient.invalidateQueries({
predicate: (query) => query.queryKey.startsWith('getWidgetAdmin')})
```

Comment: Wow, I thought the key had to be a string; using arrays makes much more sense, and switching to array keys instantly solved my problem and opened up several possibilities for my app.  Many thanks!

Comment: @TkDodo Would it be possible to invalidate 

`['getWidgetAdmin', 'some', more, filters]`
with 
`queryClient.invalidateQueries(['some'])`
?

Comment: It is if you use objects instead of arrays. Arrays have an order. See: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/leveraging-the-query-function-context#object-query-keys